# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk - get visitor IP address (python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, bottle, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My application is developed in python and the [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) framework. I am using following code snippet to get IP address of visitors to the page:

```
user_ip = bottle.request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

It works fine on my local machine, however, after deployment to the AWS Beanstalk instance, I think I am getting the load balancer IP, as the user_ip reads something like 10.48.95.234.

Is my thinking correct? If so, is there any way to obtain real visitor's ip address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that the `REMOTE_ADDR` value you are getting is for the ELB.

You would typically need to look for the `X-Forwarded-For` header in the request.  The ELB will insert this header to let you know the end client IP address.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a bottle-specific version that helps out in this case:

```
user_ip = bottle.request.remote_addr
```

This automagically does the processing and gets user's address. See [documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.remote_addr) or [source code](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/_modules/bottle.html#BaseRequest.remote_route) for more details.

Comment: Does that also check for X-Forwarded-For ?

Comment: It works for me on the ELB - and if the above poster's statement is correct, it means that ti does that too. Do you have opposite experience?

Answer (score 0):

This works for my ELB:

```
from bottle import route, run, request

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello, {}".format(request.remote_route)

run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, server='twisted')
```