# Amazon Beanstalk get visitor IP address (React - Docker)

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, docker, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My question is pretty much the React/Docker version of this one [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk - get visitor IP address (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241704/amazon-elastic-beanstalk-get-visitor-ip-address-python).

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment that runs a container of mine with a React application. Everything runs smoothly, but I wonder how can I retrieve information as which IPs are visiting my environment.

I am able to access the log files through these steps: Panel -> Elastic Beanstalk -> Environments -> Selecting environment -> Logs -> Download logs. The issue then is that under `/var/log/nginx/access.log` (and every where else as well) there is only what I assume is the remote address of ELB.

What is the best practice to get such IPs? Do I have to deal with nginx, or more a package-library inside npm/react?